# Microsoft SQL Server: How to get next available integer from an arbitrary range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to migrate data from one table to another in Microsoft SQL Server. When migrating to the new table, I want to assign the next available integer from a range of 0-127 for a certain column.

A basic implementation is:
`INSERT INTO table (columnName) SELECT MAX(columnName)+1 FROM table`

However this does not deal with the arbitary range of 0 - 127. How would I restrict the operation to this range?

I should also add, I do NOT want to use Identity Inserts here, even though it might make sense.

EDIT: After the 0-127 values have been taken, it should loop back around and start again.

Comment: Hint:  `identity` column.

Comment: Without using identity - i will edit the question to make that clear sorry!

Comment: Then use [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: BTW `MAX(columnName)+1` will easily return duplicate values, eg if the maximum record gets deleted

Comment: What should happen if if you have more than 128 rows in the table that needs to migrate?

Comment: Would it help if you knew that SQL has a MODULO function?

Comment: after 128 rows, it should start the cycle again back from 0-127

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - sadly Sequence can not be used in Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

the query you showed, will insert the next number for every record.

what you want is to use row_number() + MAX(columnName)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Edit: for limitting the numbers to the specified max value, and on that point get back to the start, you can go for something like this, even throught I don't see where this could be usefull:

```
case when (row_number() over(columnName) + max(columnName)) > 127
then (row_number() over(columnName) + max(columnName)) % 127
else row_number() over(columnName) + max(columnName)
end
```